# Word separators for Postgres full text search with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I'm using [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) for some text searching within my model. Among other attributes, I have an `url` field.

Unfortuantelly Postgres doesn't seem to identify `/` and `.` as word separators, therefore I cannot search within the `url`.

Example: searching for `test` in http://test.com yields no results.

Is there a way to fix this problem, perhaps using another gem or some inline SQL ?

Comment: as a work-around you could have another column/attribute with the url and recognized word separators, and search against that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem to support arbitrary ts_vector expressions instead of just column names.
The changes are [here](https://github.com/mihaifm/pg_search/commit/8026c102156f670dd1a9779da5acf5686c345588)

Now I can write:

```
pg_search_scope :search, 
    against: [[:title , 'B'], ["to_tsvector(regexp_replace(url, '[^\\w]+', ' ', 'gi'))", 'A']],
    using: {tsearch: {dictionary: "simple"}}
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the documentation (and noticed by AJcodez), there is a solution in creating a dedicated column for tsvector index. Then define a trigger that catches insertions to index urls properly:

```
CREATE test_url (url varchar NOT NULL, url_tsvector tsvector NOT NULL);
```

This method will transorm any non alpha characters into single space and turn the string into a tsvector:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_url_tsvector(varchar) 
RETURNS tsvector 
LANGUAGE sql 
AS $_$
    SELECT to_tsvector(regexp_replace($1, '[^\w]+', ' ', 'gi'));
$_$;
```

Now create a trigger that calls this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_test_url()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $_$
BEGIN;
  NEW.url_tsvector := generate_url_tsvector(NEW.url); 

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$_$
;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_test_url_trig 
BEFORE INSERT ON test_url 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_insert_test_url();
```

Now, when url are inserted, the `url_tsvectorè field will be automatically populated.

```
INSERT INTO test_url (url) VALUES ('http://www.google.fr');
TABLE test_url;

 id          url                     url_tsvector            

  2  http://www.google.fr  'fr':4 'googl':3 'http':1 'www':2 

(1 row)
```

To FT search on URLs you only need to query against this field.

```
SELECT * FROM test_url WHERE url_tsvector @@ 'google'::tsquery;
```

Comment: You don't even need the extra column if you use a [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-expressional.html). Further, you can create a [view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-views.html) to avoid the need to specify the full form of the expression used to create the index when performing a query.

Comment: I hacked that gem to support arbitrary ts_vector calls, which will allow me to use `regexp_replace`, as you suggested. 
Using insert/update triggers might have the benefit of performance, but I find this solution a bit too cumbersome for my needs.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simpler approach, add the protocol token type to the `simple` dictionary:

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple
    ADD MAPPING FOR protocol
        WITH simple;
```

you can also add it to the `english` dictionary if you need stemming

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-parsers.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altertsconfig.html